# Amplify GraphQL query filtering is not working as expected

Tags: filter, graphql, aws-amplify

The following two queries should return the same output, but they don't.
I am trying to load links between users on a map, since we have too much payload, I need to split the loading. Therefore I have to use this query to load the links that are necessary.

As mentioned the issue I am having is that these two return different results, which in my opinion they shouldn't. We are using GraphQL with Amplify inside of an React application. The data is stored on AWS.

entry in db:
source: "b864749a-c4bf-4c93-93db-dfa868ffc31d"
target: "cf7f4036-2df2-47ee-a3d7-96b77fc7fd1c"

giving no result:

```
query ListLinks(
  $nextToken: String
) {
  listLinks(filter: {
    or: [{
      and: [{
          source: { eq: "b864749a-c4bf-4c93-93db-dfa868ffc31d" },
          target: { eq: "cf7f4036-2df2-47ee-a3d7-96b77fc7fd1c" }
      }],
      and: [{
          source: { eq: "cf7f4036-2df2-47ee-a3d7-96b77fc7fd1c" },
          target: { eq: "b864749a-c4bf-4c93-93db-dfa868ffc31d" }
        }]   
    }] 
  }, limit: 999, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      source
      target
      relation
      verified
      talentMap {
        id
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

giving result:

```
query ListLinks(
  $nextToken: String
) {
  listLinks(filter: {
    or: [{
      and: [{
          target: { eq: "b864749a-c4bf-4c93-93db-dfa868ffc31d" },
          source: { eq: "cf7f4036-2df2-47ee-a3d7-96b77fc7fd1c" }
      }],
      and: [{
          target: { eq: "cf7f4036-2df2-47ee-a3d7-96b77fc7fd1c" },
          source: { eq: "b864749a-c4bf-4c93-93db-dfa868ffc31d" }
        }]   
    }] 
  }, limit: 999, nextToken: $nextToken) {
    items {
      id
      source
      target
      relation
      verified
      talentMap {
        id
        createdAt
        updatedAt
      }
      createdAt
      updatedAt
    }
    nextToken
  }
}
```

Any idea why this is the case?